# Multiple regression line of best fit

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a line using ggplot2 to a multiple regression but dont know the best way to do this. What I am looking at is the effect of logging on the mass of different trophic groups of beetles. I have 5 different trophic groups, and I don't know if the graph will look too messy. So far I have tried to fit it just on the 'carnivores' group with the following code:

```
ggplot(data=dat[dat$TL1=="Carnivorous"], aes(x= agb, y=Mass)) + 
  geom_point(color="blue") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se= FALSE)
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is very difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply [it doesn't work](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking). Please edit your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for hints on what makes a good explanation. Don't forget to provide a working [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you're trying to subset the data frame `dat`, there's a comma missing. I think you wanted `data = dat[dat$TL1 == "Carnivorous", ]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(agb, Mass) +
  geom_point(aes(color = TL1)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(group = TL1, color = TL1))
```